# Applying static keyword to a class in java

Tags: java

My problem is regarding the application of Static keyword for a class. 
As it is easy to apply static keyword for instance variables and methods but
while coming to classes it is not working.
finally please help me to solve the code

```
static class Box{
    static int width,depth,height;
    static void volume(int w,int d,int h){
        double vol=w*d*h;
        System.out.println(vol);
    }
}

class ClassStaticTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Box b=new Box();
        width=10;
        height=10;
        depth=10;
        Box.volume(10,10,10);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Top-level classes cannot be `static`, because the `static` keyword represents a relation between a class/member/method and the enclosing class.

As the top-level classes don't have an enclosing class, then the `static` keyword doesn't makes sense in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to make non-inner classes static.

static means: on the level of the containing class, and not instance of it.

In what you try to do: there is no containing class.

Answer (score 0):

Only nested (inner) classes may be static. `static` has no meaning with regular classes